# Move element by certain amount while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I want to move the white box to the right by 50% while scrolling until it reaches the red section. The distance to the red section is 1000px in the example.

[image]

The code below moves the box to the right as I scroll down, and I'm just using a random number `10` to slow down the movement but I can't get my head around to make it move evenly for every scroll event until the box reaches the red section and move 50% to the right.

```js
var xPos = 0;

function getXPos(target, windowPos) {
  var amount = windowPos - target;
  xPos = amount / 10;
  return xPos;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  var sectionOne = $('section.one').offset().top;
  var sectionTwo = $('section.two').offset().top;
  var box = $('.box');

  if (windowPos > sectionOne && windowPos < sectionTwo) {
    box.css({
      "transform": 'translateX(' + getXPos(sectionOne, windowPos) + '%)'
    });
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

section.one {
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}

section.two {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="two"></section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is also another issue with scroll that if I scroll too fast, the box won't move as much.
Here is the fiddle for demonstration.
https://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/0Lspo2d9/

Comment: `xPos = amount / 10;` is 10 a magic number?

Comment: No, it’s just there to slow down the movement. So it’s not a meaningful number. Thanks for showing interest.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the logic of making a progress bar for whole page but for your section with class "one". So when you scroll the section 100% of it's height the "left" css property on the div with class "box" becomes at value of "100%". But as I understood we need to stop moving when we reach section with class "two" with div with class "box". So {left: 100%} will become when we have scrolled whole section with class "box" minus the visible height of div with class "box". Then it is easily calculated to move only for 50% of width of section with class "one" (-width of div with class "box" width / 2 to center it). Hope I described my solution clearly (xd). Hope it helps
The code:

```js
one = document.querySelector(".one")
two = document.querySelector(".two")
box = document.querySelector(".box")

$(window).on('scroll', function (){
    if (window.scrollY >= (one.scrollHeight - box.offsetHeight)) {
        $('.box').css('left', `calc(50% - ${(box.offsetWidth / 2)}px`);
        return
    }
    $scrolledFrom = $(document).scrollTop();
    $documentHeight = $(document).height() - ($(".two").height() + box.offsetHeight);
    $leftOffset = ($scrolledFrom / $documentHeight) * 100;
    $('.box').css('left', `calc(${($leftOffset / 2)}% - ${(box.offsetWidth / 2)}px`);
    console.log ()
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
  
.box {
    background: white;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
  
section.one {
    height: 1000px;
    background: blue;
}
  
section.two {
    height: 1000px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
        <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="two"></section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```